# ggplot colour_gradient2() - midpoint works unexpected

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have want to create a line plot with a gradient colouring aesthetic if a certain value drops below a threshold:

```
library(tidyverse)
foo <- tribble(
    ~x, ~y, ~c
    , 1, 1, 1
    , 2, 2, 2
    , 3, 3, 3
    , 4, 4, 4
)

foo %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, y, colour = c)) +
    geom_line(size = 3) +
    scale_colour_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "green", high = "green", midpoint = 3)
```

[image]

I want to create multiple of these plots **with the same colouring logic**, i.e. a gradient between green and red for 1 <= c <= 3. But when the underlying data changes, the colour gradient changes as well:

```
foo <- tribble(
    ~x, ~y, ~c
    , 1, 1, 1
    , 2, 2, 2
    , 3, 3, 3
    , 4, 4, 100
)

foo %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, y, colour = c)) +
    geom_line(size = 3) +
    scale_colour_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "green", high = "green", midpoint = 3)
```

[image]

I hope someone has a better answer than recalculating the underlying variable (`foo %>% mutate(c = ifelse(c > 4, 4, c))`).

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `scale_color_gradientn` with `scales::rescale`. The rescale function default is `to = c(0, 1)`, meaning, the vector of values is rescaled to values in that range.

```
foo %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, colour = c)) +
  geom_line(size = 3) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colors = c("red", "green", "green"), 
                         values = scales::rescale(foo$c))
```

[image]

Comment: How does this work? The code doesn't specify anywhere that 3 is supposed to be the midpoint.

Comment: @Georgery But it rescaled the values, the small values are close to the coordinates' values and the midpoint  color is green. There is 1 value above 3 and 1 value below 2, so the transition and the midpoint are between these.

Comment: OK, I tried it. This is **not** the answer. This solution works coincidentally with the sample data, but for example if there are more values above 100, the colour scale changes.